# Change in square root?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm looking at an example problem where $\sqrt{1-(x^2/36)}$ is changed to $\sqrt{36-x^2}$ with no explanation. How does that work?

Comment: It doesn't, it ought to be $\frac16\sqrt{36-x^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

You probably missed a factor of $\frac 16$.  It is true that $\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{36}}=\frac 16\sqrt {36-x^2}$

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I was using the chain rule and the 1/6 that factored out was actually negative, while the inner term was positive 1/6 so they cancelled each other out. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It is just some basic algebra:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
1-\frac{x^2}{36} &\equiv& \frac{36}{36}-\frac{x^2}{36} \\ \\ \\
&\equiv& \frac{36-x^2}{36}\end{eqnarray*}$$

It follows then that 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{36}} &\equiv& \sqrt{\frac{36-x^2}{36}} \\ \\ \\
&\equiv& \frac{\sqrt{36-x^2}}{\sqrt{36}} \\ \\ \\
&\equiv& \frac{\sqrt{36-x^2}}{6} \\ \\ \\
&\equiv& \tfrac{1}{6}\sqrt{36-x^2}
\end{eqnarray*}$$